# AngularJS and Cordova- Detect Device Ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on an app using AngularJS. Now, I'm ready to take my app and bundle it up with Cordova. My issue is, I'm not sure how to handle the `ondeviceready` event. At this time, my app is setup like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.protocol === "file:") {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeApp(), false);
    } else {
      initializeApp();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
function initializeApp() {
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
  myApp.config(function() {
    ...
  });

  myApp.run(function() {
    ...
  });
}
```

I put the initialization in a function called initializeApp so I could reuse it. However, when I attempt to run this, I'm getting an error that says...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova + Angularjs + Device Ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556090/cordova-angularjs-device-ready)

Comment: not a duplicate. My code sample is trying to manually bootstrap the app. The problem is sharing the code via initializeApp such that I don't have to copy-and-paste the code if the app is running in phonegap or in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact issue is, but I know the following piece of code is incorrect

Change

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeApp(), false);
```

To

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeApp, false);
```

By doing it the first way, you're trying to execute the function instantly.

Comment: where do you put that?