# "device is not defined" : Codrova/Ionic + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am getting the very common `device is not defined` error when I load my Ionic application in both the browser (via `ionic serve`) and on my device.

I am new to TypeScript and I think my trouble may be related to some misunderstandings there.

My `index.html` contains (note that `ng-app` is missing from my DOM element):

```
    <link href="css/ionic.app.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova-mocks.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/src/plugins/device.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/src/plugins/file.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div ui-view=""></div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrapApp.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here, `app.js` is compiled from TypeScript. I have quite a bit going on in here, but the interesting part is this:

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app", [
        "ionic",
        "ngCordova",
        "ui.router"
    ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("splash", {
            url: "/splash",
            templateUrl: "components/splash/splash.html",
            controller: "SplashController"
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");
    });
})(App || (App = {}));
var App;
(function (App) {
    "use strict";
    var DeviceService = (function () {
        function DeviceService($cordovaDevice) {
            this.device = null;
            this.device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
            console.log(this.device);
        }
        DeviceService.$inject = ["$cordovaDevice"];
        return DeviceService;
    })();
    angular.module("app").service("DeviceService", DeviceService);
})(App || (App = {}));
```

To ensure that my device is "ready", I followed a suggestion I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975700/3817101

So, I have a `bootstrapApp.js` file that contains:

```
window.ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    console.log("platform is ready");
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

On page load, everything appears to be happy, except for the use of `$cordovaDevice`. My console reads:

```
platform is ready
ionic.bundle.js:20306 ReferenceError: device is not defined
```

It's obvious that I'm attempting to use the device before things are "ready" but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if you need a specific ionic command, but you need a cordova plugin: `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code you posted (you would need something like `this.device.foo` to get an error and no such `.foo` in your code).

## Solution

The ordering of the JS files can cause this. Change :

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova-mocks.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/src/plugins/device.js"></script>
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/src/plugins/file.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

To :

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova-mocks.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/src/plugins/device.js"></script>
<script src="lib/node_modules/ng-cordova/src/plugins/file.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->

<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Moving the `ionic.bundle.js` script causes several more problems since that includes Angular.

Also, my `device is not defined` error is caused by the line: `this.device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();` (commenting it out results in no errors in the console)