# Change log level of Cordova Console Plugin

Tags: cordova, logging, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, console.log

Does anyone know how to change the logLevel of the Cordova Plugin Console (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) from "WARN" to "DEBUG"?

Answer (score 0):

Currently is not possible without modifying the console plugin.

You can add to `console-via-logger.js` (the one outside the platform directory):

```
console.setLevel = function(level) {
  logger.level(level);
};
```

And call it from your code as:

```
console.setLevel('DEBUG')
```

But note it'll only work from a device and the $log service won't work either.
Only `console.log`, `console.debug`, `console.info`,...

A better alternative is enable the Safari Web Inspector in the device and remote inspect from Safari, and for Android use the Chrome ADB plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to modify the plugin. You can set the log level with:

`cordova.logger.level(cordova.logger.DEBUG);`

If you are using AngularJS make sure that you bootstrap angular after the `deviceReady` event. The AngularJS `$log` service caches the reference to the `console` object but this is replaced by the cordova console plugin.

See: [Cordova + Angularjs + Device Ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556090/cordova-angularjs-device-ready)