# ionic app.run deviceready rootscoop variable not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-rootscope

In my ionic app I have the app.run function and a device ready function inside it:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaPush) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

    }, false);
})
```

When I declare a rootScope variable in the run function like below the variable is available in all controllers.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaPush) {

    $rootScope.myvariable = 'teststring';

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

    }, false);
})
```

When I place the rootScope variable inside the deviceready function the rootScope variable is not available anymore

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaPush) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

        // I need this variable here because it's a value generated by a function that only works inside the deviceready function

        $rootScope.myvariable = 'teststring';

    }, false);
})
```

How can I make the rootscope variable inside the deviceready function available for all my controller ?

Comment: myvariable will still be available but only after deviceready. So when you try to access it device is just not ready yet.What are you trying to do with that variable.

Comment: I need the variable throughout my app in other functions in different controllers. The variable contains device info and unfortunately I can only retrieve that information in that location and no where els. It's about the device token for the push notification service.

Comment: Checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556090/cordova-angularjs-device-ready