# CallLog access plugin in cordova is not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Hi I am developing a hybrid application using cordova. I am trying to access the last call that is missed in an android mobile using CallLog plugin.This is what I have tried,

```
1.I installed the plugin with this command cordova plugin add https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin.git.
2.I am using angularJS.I have this app.js.

var app=angular.module('lmp', ['ngCordova']);
     app.controller('lmpctrl',['$scope', 'CallLogService', function($scope, CallLogService){
        $scope.data = {};
                $scope.callTypeDisplay = function(type) {
                    switch(type) {
                        case 1:
                            return 'Incoming';
                        case 2:
                            return 'Outgoing';
                        case 3:
                            return 'Missed';
                        default:
                            return 'Unknown';
                    }};

                CallLogService.list(1).then(
                    function(callLog) {
                        console.log(callLog);
                        $scope.data.lastCall = callLog[0];
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            }]);

     app.factory('CallLogService', ['$q', function($q) {
            return {
                list : function(days) {
                    var q = $q.defer();
                    // days is how many days back to go
                    window.plugins.calllog.list(days, function (response) {
                        q.resolve(response.rows);
                    }, function (error) {
                        q.reject(error)
                    });
                    return q.promise;
                },

                contact : function(phoneNumber) {
                    var q = $q.defer();
                    window.plugins.calllog.contact(phoneNumber, function (response) {
                        q.resolve(response);
                    }, function (error) {
                        q.reject(error)
                    });
                    return q.promise;
                },

                show : function(phoneNumber) {
                    var q = $q.defer();
                    window.plugins.calllog.show(phoneNumber, function (response) {
                        q.resolve(response);
                    }, function (error) {
                        q.reject(error)
                    });
                    return q.promise;
                },

                delete : function(phoneNumber) {
                    var q = $q.defer();
                    window.plugins.calllog.delete(id, function (response) {
                        q.resolve(response);
                    }, function (error) {
                        q.reject(error)
                    });
                    return q.promise;
                }
            }
        }]);

3.This is my index.html.

<body ng-app="lmp">
        <div ng-controller="lmpctrl">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">Last Call</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Name</div>
                <div class="col">{{data.lastCall.cachedName}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Number</div>
                <div class="col">{{data.lastCall.number}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Type</div>
                <div class="col">{{callTypeDisplay(data.lastCall.type)}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Date</div>
                <div class="col">{{data.lastCall.date | date}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Duration</div>
                <div class="col">{{data.lastCall.duration}} seconds</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-30 col-offset-10">Acknowledged</div>
                <div class="col">{{(data.lastCall.new == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no')}}</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

4.I added this following code in my config.xml
<feature name="CallLog">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.ubookr.plugins.CallLogPlugin"/>
            </feature>
```

Am I missing something or Am I wrong by someway. Can someone please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: any errors in console sundar?

Comment: Iam getting this error in browser  TypeError: Cannot read property 'calllog' of undefined @SaEChowdary

Comment: @what line?i mean in controller or in factory?

Comment: here in my controller   CallLogService.list(1).then(.. @SaEChowdary

Comment: excuse me if this is stupid.....to  the function your passing calllog as parameter.....from where your getting this calllog ?

Comment: Thats not a parameter.I have a factory with a function list.I am getting the return value in then promise that is what function(calllog) or it can be function(result). @SaEChowdary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122730/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-sundar-nivash).

Comment: Hi Sundar. Are you still facing this issue? Did you try my solution or found any other better one? regards, Alvaro.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `window.plugins` is undefined. What I do to avoid that is to manually bootstrap AngularJS on `DeviceReady` event instead of using `ng-app` directive, as explained in [Cordova + Angularjs + Device Ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556090/cordova-angularjs-device-ready)

To do that, remove `ng-app` directive from your `<body>` element, and place this JavaScript on top of your `app.js` script:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    angular.bootstrap(body, ['lmp']);
}, false);
```

This will wait until the device is ready to bootstrap angular, ensuring that all the device services are available before you use them.