# Ionic 2 bootstrap after platform ready

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

My ionic2 app loads the main page and starts fetching the data using a custom DBService which in turn uses Cordova SQLite plugin, but at this time the platform is not ready and thus sqlitePlugin is not available.

How do I stop application to bootstrap until the platform is ready (and SQlite db is open)?

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556090/cordova-angularjs-device-ready) for angular1 based apps where bootstraping is delayed until 'deviceready' event is fired.

Can anybody suggest a solution for ionic2 based apps?

Comment: Update: Solved this using https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Add your method here.
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue for this case on GitHub:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/issues/114

Adjust your `main.ts` like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

function bootstrap() {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}

if (window['cordova']) {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => bootstrap());
} else {
  bootstrap();
}
```

Comment: I know, the issue was created based on this question itself. :) https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bootstrap-ionic-2-after-platform-ready/73163